# PowerShell and ffmpeg: No such file or directory

Tags: powershell, ffmpeg

I'm trying to use the below command in a Python script, however I'm seeing that it's a PowerShell issue in that it can't seem to find the video file I'm pointing to.

I have a video file on a cloud drive `Z:` at the following location (for reproducibility, change this to whatever path you want with a video file in it):

`Z:\Udemy_And_Misc_Downloads\TensorFlow Developer Certificate in 2021 Zero to Mastery\3. Neural network regression with TensorFlow\18. Setting up TensorFlow modelling experiments part 2 (increasing complexity).mp4`

Notice the spaces and special characters in the filename in case that matters.

What I'm trying to do is down-sample that video file to a smaller size with the following command:

`ffmpeg -i "Z:\Udemy_And_Misc_Downloads\TensorFlow Developer Certificate in 2021 Zero to Mastery\[TutsNode.com] - TensorFlow Developer Certificate in 2021 Zero to Mastery\3. Neural network regression with TensorFlow\18. Setting up TensorFlow modelling experiments part 2 (increasing complexity).mp4" -y -vcodec libx264 -acodec ac3 -threads 1 "Z:\Udemy_And_Misc_Downloads\TensorFlow Developer Certificate in 2021 Zero to Mastery\[TutsNode.com] - TensorFlow Developer Certificate in 2021 Zero to Mastery\3. Neural network regression with TensorFlow\18. Setting up TensorFlow modelling experiments part 2 (increasing complexity)DOWNSAMPLED.mp4"`

I know it's long as it's mostly consumed by the filenames, but the error I'm getting is:

`Z:\Udemy_And_Misc_Downloads\TensorFlow Developer Certificate in 2021 Zero to Mastery\[TutsNode.com] - TensorFlow  Developer Certificate in 2021 Zero to Mastery\3. Neural network regression with TensorFlow\18. Setting up TensorFlow  modelling experiments part 2 (increasing complexity).mp4: No such file or directory`

The path IS correct, as it's a direct copy paste from the folder's URL bar.

The things I've tried include:

- using quotes around filename
- not using quotes around filename
- prepending quoted filename with "r" (where I got message saying `did you mean file:r?)
- prepending quoted filename with "file:r"
- used double slashes \ in filepaths

Is there a powershell pro out there that can tell me why it can't "find" the file?

**UPDATE**
The command runs if I find a filename with:

```
$oldvids = Get-ChildItem *.mp4, *mov, *wmv, *avi -Recurse
foreach ($oldvid in $oldvids) 
{
    $newvid = [io.path]::ChangeExtension($oldvid.FullName, '_.mp4')
    ffmpeg -i $oldvid.FullName -y -vcodec libx264 -acodec ac3 -threads 1 $newvid
}
```

When I print the `$oldvid.name` and `$oldvid.FullName`, the paths/filenames look like this:

```
Z:\Udemy_And_Misc_Downloads\TensorFlow Developer Certificate in 2021 Zero to Mastery\5. Computer Vision and Convolutional Neu
ral Networks in TensorFlow\35. Multi-class CNN's part 9 Making predictions with our model on custom images.mp4

35. Multi-class CNN's part 9 Making predictions with our model on custom images.mp4
```

...that first one being an exact copy of what I'm trying to use in my posted code. So what's the difference??

**SECOND UPDATE**
I think the issue lies in that the file is located on a drive other than `C:`. Just tested it by moving the file onto my computer and running the command, and it worked. So I guess, is there a way to tell PowerShell to use the `Z:` drive to find the file?

Comment: There might be a long path (>260 chars) issue on the cloud drive. Quick idea: `Set-Location -LiteralPath "Z:\Udemy_And_Misc_Downloads\TensorFlow Developer Certificate in 2021 Zero to Mastery\[TutsNode.com] - TensorFlow  Developer Certificate in 2021 Zero to Mastery\3. Neural network regression with TensorFlow"` and then pass only the file name to ffmpeg.

Comment: You might also try to set a symbolic link from that long folder path to a short path on your local disk: `mklink /d c:\shortpath "Z:\Udemy_And_Misc_Downloads\TensorFlow Developer Certificate in 2021 Zero to Mastery\[TutsNode.com] - TensorFlow  Developer Certificate in 2021 Zero to Mastery\3. Neural network regression with TensorFlow"` and then pass the short path to ffmpeg.

Comment: Your error doesn't make sense to me; the command `ffmpeg -i "Z:\"` is simply building a string and passing it as a parameter to ffmpeg. In that command, *Powershell* is not looking inside the string to see if it's a file, or trying to find or use the file. So where exactly is `No such file or directory` coming from? What's the full error message?

Comment: PowerShell's file not found message is `kjh : The term 'kjh' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program`. Command prompt is `'kjh' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`. So is it ffmpeg which is generating the error message? If so, then why does `ffmpeg -i $oldvid.FullName` behave differently?

Comment: I have discovered the issue, and it was a problem with how I was constructing the command through the variables I was using. Completely my mistake. I will post a simplified script with the working answer for anyone wanting it in the future. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem was that some of the file names had special characters in them (probably from another operating system), like `'`. Once I deleted those, the issues went away. My mistake.

BUT, I have created a simplified script that might help others in case they want it. I would improve upon this script by adding in some error checking, checking for already downsampled video files (which I'm denoting with a `._` in the filename but anything can be used), etc., but here ya go:

```
import subprocess
import os.path
import os

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                                         GLOBAL VARIABLES                                         #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
types = (".mp4", ".mov", ".wmv", ".avi") # the tuple of file types
directory_to_recurse = r"Z:\Python_Projects\Misc\Video_Reformatter"

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                            HELPER FUNCTION - RUN A POWERSHELL COMMAND                            #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
def run_powershell_command(cmd):
    completed = subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", cmd], capture_output=True)
    return completed

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
#                                          SIMPLIFIED TEST                                         #
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ #
# Recursively iterate through all folders in "directory_to_recurse", finding video files
# along the way
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory_to_recurse):
    # Inspect
    print(root, "\n", dirs, "\n", files, "\n")
    for file in files:
        # If we've found a video file...
        if file.endswith(types):
            # ...parse some data
            full_path_and_file = os.path.join(root, file)
            filename_only = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
            extension_only = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
            # Inspect
            print(full_path_and_file,"\n", filename_only,"\n", extension_only,"\n")
            # Run the ffmpeg downsampling command
            result = run_powershell_command("ffmpeg -i '" + full_path_and_file + 
                                            "' -y -vcodec libx264 -acodec ac3 -threads 2 '" + 
                                            str(root) + "\\" + str(filename_only) + "._" + 
                                            str(extension_only) + "'")
            # Inspect the result object (if desired)
            print("result:", result)
            # If we receive a return code of anything over 0, exit
            if result.returncode >= 1:
                print("ERROR!")
                exit(result.returncode)
            # Once we've successfully downsampled the video, delete the original
            os.remove(os.path.join(root, full_path_and_file))
            continue
```